# Problems reseting panel after using force_panelsizes of package gghx4

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, rstudio

How can I reset my plot panel after using force_panelsizes of package gghx4 ? Since I have used this function on a ggplot (and decided not to use it) my plotting panel seems to be stuck with the setup caused by this function.

My plots look for example like this before and now (I had to blur some data due to privacy reasons):

BEFORE

[image]

AFTER

[image]

So the first plot uses almost the whole page, the second is still limited by width and height.

I already reinstalled my R version (4.1.0), R Studio version (2022.02.3), ggplot2 and my latex-version of tinytex. The plots are part of a knitted report. I had to blur some parts due to privacy reasons.

A `MRE` Example of the code I'm using (with minimal change in data for privacy reasons and minimal changes in the used margins for the title, caption and x-Axis because of the small plot area - otherwise no bars would have been plotted):

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
classoption: a4paper
geometry: left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,includeheadfoot
fontsize: 11pt
lang: de
header-includes:
-   \usepackage{caption}
-   \captionsetup[figure]{font={footnotesize,rm}}
-   \captionsetup[table]{font={footnotesize,rm}}
-   \usepackage{lastpage}
-   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
-   \pagestyle{fancy}
-   \fancyhf{}
-   \fancyhead[R]{\fontsize{9}{11} \selectfont \leftmark}
-   \fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{9}{11} \selectfont Spezialauswertung}
-   \fancyfoot[R]{\fontsize{9}{0} \selectfont Seite \thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
---

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(cbind(
    Pop=rep(1:3,8),
    Question_Cat=rep(1:8,each=3),
    Values=c(84,89,100,92,100,10,82,91,100,26,18,26,76,90,77,52,36,50,83,100,100,72,81,73),
    n=c(129,11,19,90,11,19,101,11,19,127,11,19,126,11,18,120,11,7,127,11,19,125,11,19),
    sort=rep(1:8,each=3))
  )

lab <- c("Question 1","Question 2","Question 3","Question 4","Question 5","Question 6","Question 7","Question 8")
names(lab) <- as.character(1:8)


ggplot(data=df,aes(x=1,y=Values)) +
  geom_bar(aes(group=Pop,fill=factor(Pop)),stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ sort,nrow=8,labeller=labeller(.default=lab,.multi_line = FALSE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#5ba755","#ddebf7","#acb9ca"),labels=c("Group 1","Group 2","Group 3")) +
  coord_flip() +
  ylim(-2,100) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(round(Values,2),"%"),group=Pop),position = position_dodge(0.9),hjust=-0.4,vjust=0.35,size=rel(2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste("n=",n),y=0,group=Pop),position = position_dodge(0.9),hjust=1.2,size=rel(2)) +
  theme_classic() +    
      theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank(),legend.text=element_text(size=rel(0.6)),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=rel(1.1),face="bold",margin=margin(25,0,5,0)),
        plot.caption.position="plot",plot.caption = element_text(size=rel(0.7),margin=margin(0,0,0,0)),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size=rel(0.8),face="italic",hjust=0),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(0.7),margin=margin(0,0,0,0)),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.85),margin=margin(0,0,0,0))) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  ylab("Prozent") +
  xlab("") +
  labs(title="Some Plot Title here",subtitle="",caption = "Some explanation here")

```
````

The PDF-Output looks like this (still wrong):

[image]

In all 3 outputs header and footer are not shown.

I also tried to close the plotting panels with dev.off() but there is only the NULL device left:
`Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)`

Any ideas of what went wrong?

Any help is really appreciated :))))))))))))))))

Thank you!

Comment: `force_panelsizes()` only affects the plot you're adding it to. It doesn't transfer to new plots, and it doesn't transcend R sessions. Your plot looks fine if given more height, so I'd change the chunk options to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks teunbrand, that was the solution - adding fig.height & fig.width :)